# Python list of dictionaries: How to tell if value doesn't exist

Tags: python, list

I have a JSON query that returns a list of dictionaries that I want to modify. Here is the part that interests me in the response:

```
{
    #...
    "publisher_bid_modifier": {
        "values": [{
                "target": "msn-can",
                "cpc_modification": 1.5
            },
            {
                "target": "msn-can-home",
                "cpc_modification": 1.5
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The print(temp) in the code below will return:

```
[{"target": "msn-can-home","cpc_modification": 0.5}, {"target": "msn-can","cpc_modification": 0.5}]
```

After that, I extract the data I want to modify from the db and match it with the data extracted from the JSON response.

I can easily modify "cpc_modification" if the value of "target" exists in the db. My problem is to be able to do something else when the "target" value doesn't exist in the response.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
print(temp)

for dt in temp:
    theCursor.execute('SELECT ADJUST, SITE FROM SandboxPubTB WHERE CAMPAIGNNAME =?', (campaignName,) ) 
    campaignRows = theCursor.fetchall()
    for t in campaignRows:

        if t[1] == dt['target'] :
            dt['cpc_modification'] = "{:.2f}".format((int(t[0]) / 100) + 1)
            print("exists")
        #if dt['target'] not in t[1] :
        else:
            temp.append({'target': '"' + t[1] + "'", 'cpc_modification': "'" + str(t[0]) + "'"})
            print("Doesn't exists") 

print(temp)
```

In the else I'm trying to append a new list entry with the new "target" and "cpc_modification" but the output is an infinite loop of the the print("Doesn't exists").

The closest I came to the solution is this:

```
elif dt['target'] not in temp:
```

But this will iterate as many time as the number of entries in the temp list.

To give an example with input and output:

**Input:**

```
[{
    'target': 'msn-can',
    'cpc_modification': 1.5
}, {
    'target': 'msn-can-home',
    'cpc_modification': 1.5
}, {
    'target': 'foxnews-foxnews',
    'cpc_modification': 1.5
}, {
    'target': 'beachraider',
    'cpc_modification': 0.69
}, {
    'target': 'crowdyfan',
    'cpc_modification': 0.7
}, {
    'target': 'novelodge',
    'cpc_modification': 0.75
}, {
    'target': 'foxnews-androidapp',
    'cpc_modification': 0.5
}, {
    'target': 'foxnews-foxbusiness',
    'cpc_modification': 1.12
}, {
    'target': 'foxnews-iosapp',
    'cpc_modification': 0.86
}, {
    'target': 'thehindu-hindunews',
    'cpc_modification': 0.7
}, {
    'target': 'vitaminnews',
    'cpc_modification': 1.46
}]
```

Database:

[image]

Output:

```
[{
    'target': 'msn-can',
    'cpc_modification': 0.5 <----
}, {
    'target': 'msn-can-home',
    'cpc_modification': 0.5 <----
}, {
    'target': 'foxnews-foxnews',
    'cpc_modification': 1.5
}, {
    'target': 'beachraider',
    'cpc_modification': 0.69
}, {
    'target': 'crowdyfan',
    'cpc_modification': 0.7
}, {
    'target': 'novelodge',
    'cpc_modification': 0.75
}, {
    'target': 'foxnews-androidapp',
    'cpc_modification': 0.5
}, {
    'target': 'foxnews-foxbusiness',
    'cpc_modification': 1.12
}, {
    'target': 'foxnews-iosapp',
    'cpc_modification': 0.86
}, {
    'target': 'thehindu-hindunews',
    'cpc_modification': 0.7
}, {
    'target': 'vitaminnews',
    'cpc_modification': 1.46
}], {
    'target': 'msn-outlookcom-canada', <----
    'cpc_modification': 0.5 <----
}]
```

Your help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

**EDIT**

The code above addresses only one campaign *campaignName variable", but the whole code should be able to treat more than one campaign. So here is an other example:

**input**

*Campaign 1:*

```
[{
    'target': 'msn-can',
    'cpc_modification': 0.5
}, {
    'target': 'msn-can-home',
    'cpc_modification': 0.5
}]
```

*Campaign 2:*

```
[{
    'target': 'fox-news',
    'cpc_modification': 0.9
}, {
    'target': 'fox-news-home',
    'cpc_modification': 0.6
}]
```

**data in db**

*Campaign 1:*

```
target: msn-can, cpc_modification: 7
target: msn-can-home, cpc_modification: 10
```

*Campaign 2:*

```
target: fox-news, cpc_modification: 20
target: fox-news-home, cpc_modification: 30
target: msn-us, cpc_modification: 10
```

**Output**

*Campaign 1:*

```
[{
    'target': 'msn-can',
    'cpc_modification': 1.07
}, {
    'target': 'msn-can-home',
    'cpc_modification': 1.1
}]
```

*Campaign 2:*

```
[{
    'target': 'fox-news',
    'cpc_modification': 1.2
}, {
    'target': 'fox-news-home',
    'cpc_modification': 1.3
}], {
    'target': 'msn-us',
    'cpc_modification': 1.1
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

re-group your data so that you have a dictionary keyed by the target.

```
rekey = {t['target']: t for t in temp}
```

then you can just look for your data naturally

```
theCursor.execute('SELECT ADJUST, SITE FROM SandboxPubTB WHERE CAMPAIGNNAME =?', (campaignName,) ) 
campaignRows = theCursor.fetchall()
for t in campaignRows:
    fmt_value = "{:.2f}".format((int(t[0]) / 100) + 1)
    try:
        print(f"updating {t[1]}")
        rekey[t[1]]['cpc_modification'] = fmt_value
    except KeyError:
        print(f"Adding new key {t[1]}")
        rekey[t[1]] = {'target': t[1], 'cpc_modification': fmt_value}

from pprint import pprint
pprint(rekey.values())
```

Comment: First, thank you for taking the time to answer. I have a problem with the code. In fact, the code that I posted only addresses the modifications made to one campaign at a time, but with the code you shared, it considers different campaigns as one and appends 'target' and 'cpc_modification' where it doesn't belong. Instead of two different dict_values, in case of 2 differents campaigns inputs, I get only one dict_values with all the db data appended to it.

Comment: I've updated my code with another example. Thank you again.

Comment: Your db query appears to only be looking at one "campaign" at a time.  The approach I'm suggesting can be generalized - you want to re-group your data so that your "keys" - campaign and site - are the keys in your dict.  Then it's natural to index down through them, something like `data[campaign][site] = {"cpc": value}`